# How can I plot a differential equation using plotly

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, interactive, r-plotly

I have wanted to graph the above code using [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) but I have not succeeded. I don't know very well how to use that library and for now I have only been able to [plot](/questions/tagged/plot) it using the `plot()` function but I would like the outputs to be interactive.

```
library(deSolve)

## == derivative ==
fn <- function(t, N, r) {
  # dN/dt = r * N
  list(r * N)
}

r <- 1       # Parameter value
N <- 0:100   # sequence of N
t <- 0       # dummy as the derivative is not time dependent

plot(N, fn(t, N, r)[[1]], type="l")

## == integration ==
t <- seq(0, 5, .1)  # time
N0 <- 2             # initial state

## numerical solver
out <- ode(N0, t, fn, r)
plot(out, lwd=2, main="exp")

## for comparison: analytical integration
lines(t, N0*exp(r*t), lwd=2, lty="dotted", col="red")
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to convert the `deSolve` object `out` into a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe), which then can be plotted using [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) and then `ggplotly` (a plotly wrapper):

```
out <- ode(N0, t, fn, r)
out_df <- as.data.frame(ode(N0, t, fn, r))
colnames(out_df)[2] <- "Y" #changing the column name which was `1`. 

#making the ggplot object `ggp` and then using `ggplotly` to make it interactive.
library(ggplot2); library(plotly) ;
ggp <- ggplot(out_df, aes(x = time, y = Y)) + geom_line();
ggplotly(ggp); #check in the `viewer` tab of RStudio, not in the `Plots` tab.
```

Is this what you want?

**EDIT** to add the line data add another geom_line layer with `ggp` before passing to `ggplotly`:

```
ggp + geom_line(aes(N0*exp(r*t)), linetype = "dashed", color = "red") + xlim(c(0, 5))
```

**EDIT2** to respond OP's question:

You can know more about [list](/questions/tagged/list) or [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) in [r](/questions/tagged/r), [in this video](https://youtu.be/Px9VNWHja4M?t=85). To check if you got a list use this:

```
is.list(fn(t, N, r))
[1] TRUE
```

Then `[[1]]` returns the first `element` (which can be another list :P)

```
fn(t, N, r)[[1]]
  [1]   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
 [20]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37
 [39]  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56
 [58]  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75
 [77]  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94
 [96]  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

And lastly, a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) is an advanced form of a [list](/questions/tagged/list).

Comment: one question: what does [[1]] inside the plot function?

Comment: It's a classic way of spotting that you're working with a list, see `EDIT2`.

Comment: The deSolve model function returns a list with one or more elements, the first is the vector of derivatives, all other arguments are "auxillary" variables, that are to be kept in the output matrix.

Answer (score 1):

And a little bit more compact:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("plotly")
library("deSolve")

fn <- function(t, N, r) {
  list(r * N)
}

# Note: initial state as named vector y=c(N=2)
ggp <-
  ode(y = c(N = 2), times = seq(0, 5, .1), func = fn, parms = 1) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = N)) + geom_line()

ggplotly(ggp) # check in the `viewer` tab of RStudio, not in the `Plots` tab.
```